# Timer can not be repeated on android How to fix?

Tags: java, android, timertask

I want `Timer` execute repeat.
so I try this source

```
public static void init() {
    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
       @Override
       public void run() {
           Looper.prepare();
           recordWork();
           Looper.loop();
       }
    };
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000, 30000);
}
```

`init()` called when record button click.

why `recordWork()` only one `execute`?
this `timer` not execute repeat.

How to fix this problem?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the function `timer.scheduleAtFixedRate()` to execute the timer every **X** seconds.

For example `timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, new Date(), 2000)` to start the timer now and execute every 2 seconds.

Comment: I try `scheduleAtFixedRate` but only  one execute.

Comment: fix my problem,

Answer (score 0):

Use it like below

```
  public static void init() {
    TimerTask timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Looper.prepare();
            recordWork();
            Looper.loop();
        }
    };
    Timer timer = new Timer();
    timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(timerTask, 1000, 30000);
}
```

Use Timer as a global variable. and cancel it its need done.

```
 if(timer != null) {
    timer.cancel();
    timer.purge();
    timer = null;
}
```

Comment: I try scheduleAtFixedRate but only one execute.

Comment: Print Log inside timer task check if it is running after each 3 seconds . Change 3rd parameter to 3000 for testing .

Answer (score 0):

If you still can't fix your Timertask. Might as well give CountDownTimer a try
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

```
public void startCountDown() {
    countDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(totalTimeinMillis,intervalBetweenCountdown) {

                @Override
                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
                    //execute repeating task here
                }

                @Override
                public void onFinish() {

                }
            };
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use handler

```
Handler handler = new Handler();
int delay = 2000; //milliseconds

handler.postDelayed(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
        recordWork();
        handler.postDelayed(this, delay);
    }
}, delay);
```